# Print crystal report with continous paper by a thermal printer

Tags: c#, printing, crystal-reports

I am trying to design a report (using Crystal Reports for VS2010) for a receipt to be printed on a thermal printer with continuous paper.(8centimeter paper)  Now a receipt will need to have variable height according to the number of items it contains.

The problem is that Crystal Reports takes the page setup from those available in the print setup and all these paper sizes have a fixed length .

How can I set the paper to a continuos paper?

Answer (score -1):

I've a similar issue and resolved installing the printer driver on the dev machine. At that point in crystal report page setup i can see the right dimension of page.

Comment: This is not a solution. The question is like crystal report has fixed paper height specified then how to print it continuously for longer bills??? Your solution just gives paper setting or a paper height but how to set a variable paper height in crystal report is not known.